# Finding a pair on a multidimensional array using a while loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, match

How can I find a match between two numbers. If weight of `roosters_A` is equal to weight of `roosters_B`. If match the two pairs will not be match again which I had an unset function.

Here is my code:

```
$roosters = array(
                      array('weight' => 2000),
                      array('weight' => 1810),
                      array('weight' => 1810),
                      array('weight' => 1600),
                      array('weight' => 1800),
                      array('weight' => 1915),
                      array('weight' => 1700),
                      array('weight' => 2000),
                      array('weight' => 1915),
                      array('weight' => 1800)
                      );

        if(sizeof($roosters) >= 2) {
         $i = 1;
            $match = 0;
             $roosters_A  =  $roosters[0];
             while(sizeof($roosters) > $i and $match == 0) {
                 $roosters_B  =  $roosters[$i];
                 if($roosters_A['weight'] == $roosters_B['weight']) {
                    echo "$i. With Pair ".$roosters_A['weight'].' '.$roosters_B['weight'].'<br>';
                    $match = 1;
                 }  else {
                    echo "$i. No Pair ".$roosters_A['weight'].' '.$roosters_B['weight'].'<br>';
                    $match = 0;
                 }
                 $i++;  

                 unset($roosters_B);
             } 

            if($match == 1) { 
                unset($roosters_A);
            }

        }
```

I want to display this like this:

```
1. With Pair 2000 2000
2. With Pair 1810 1810
3. No Pair 1600 
4. With Pair 1800 1800
5. With Pair 1915 1915
5. No Pair 1700 
6. With Pair 2000 2000
7. With Pair 1915 1915
8. With Pair 1800 1800
```

Can you help me? I having a hard time to find a way to match it without repeating and without using any database to display this record. Many many thanks for those who will help me. I think it will be easy for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[updated to handle 3 or more pairs also]

You can do this :

```
$roosters = array(
  array('weight' => 2000),
  array('weight' => 1810),
  array('weight' => 1810),
  array('weight' => 1600),
  array('weight' => 1800),
  array('weight' => 1915),
  array('weight' => 1700),
  array('weight' => 2000),
  array('weight' => 1915),
  array('weight' => 1800),
  //added
  array('weight' => 1800),
  array('weight' => 1700),
  array('weight' => 2000),
  array('weight' => 1917),
  array('weight' => 1800)
);

$result=array();
foreach ($roosters as $rooster) {
    $key=$rooster['weight'];
    if (isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key]=$result[$key]+1;
    } else {
        $result[$key]=1;
    }
}

foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
    switch ($value) {
        case 1 : echo 'No Pair'; break;
        case 2 : echo 'With Pair'; break;
        case 3 : echo 'Three Pairs'; break;
        default : echo 'Multiple Pairs'; break;
    }
    for ($i=0;$i<$value;$i++) {
        echo '&nbsp;'.$key;
        if ($i==1) break; //break if more than two
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

outputs

```
Three Pairs 2000 2000
With Pair 1810 1810
No Pair 1600
Multiple Pairs 1800 1800
With Pair 1915 1915
With Pair 1700 1700
No Pair 1917
```

The above builds a `$result`-array which holds unique `weights`, and how many of those `weights` there is present in `$rooster`. Finally outputs the result, notifying if there is one or more of each `weight`.

Comment: thanks for the help @davidkonrad. how about three pairs? example with pair 2000 2000 2000 how can i remove the extra 2000?

Comment: @Edmar, as you can see (or try out) the algorithm dont look for two pairs exactly, or echoes two pairs out only. Have updated the answer - what I've changed is the "No pairs", "With Pair" `ternary` to a `switch` including "Three Pairs" and "Multiple Pairs". Expand / modify the `switch` for your needs. And included a break so it does not repeat say 2000 more than twice.

Comment: hi @davidkonrad. thanks for this great answer youre a genius. Sorry for too much questions. Another thing, how can I track if the match is already paired? For example three pairs 2000, 2000 and 2000 is already paired and another 2000 has no pair can this possible? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a great idea to re-invent the wheel. Good luck!

But, sometimes even **PHP** has some available functions, you might use.

In your case, e.g. these **two** (

```
assuming comparing array $roosters_A vs. $roosters_B
and $roosters_A/B is prepared like $roosters_A/B = (array) $roosters['weight'];
```

)

-

**[1]** get "No Pairs" (=unique)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

```
$no_pairs_array = array_diff($roosters_A, $roosters_B);
```

-

**[2]** get "With Pairs"

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

```
$pairs_array = array_intersect($roosters_A, $roosters_B);
```